# how can use CollapsingToolbarLayout under toolbar

Tags: android-layout, android-xml, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

this is my Xml layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">


                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/img"
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:titleTextColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                android:gravity="bottom"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is my default output:

[image]

and this is my output when drag up tabs :
[image]

but i want my app become like this : 
[image]

when drag up tabs just image between toolbar and tabs gone ...
i try so many ways but not work . if any one can please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : (Little trick with `RelativeLayout` & `LinearLayout`)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Output** :

[image]

As you requested :)

Comment: when I scroll it up it hides toolbar too